# Need to stop click again with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

when user clicks the button it shows the spinner icon until finish the task.But still user can click the button again.How can I stop it ?

[image]

[Spinner directive](https://github.com/urish/angular-spinner)

HTML

```
   <span us-spinner="{left: '91.6%',top:'65.5%',length: 5,width: 2,radius:4}" spinner-key="spinner-1"></span>
   <button class="btn btn-green" ng-click="MyClick()" ng-disabled="frmMy.$invalid"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Send</button>
```

Comment: Show some code please!!! `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have updated.Please check that.

Comment: You can add logic to MyClick() to change scope variable, for example: $scope.isLoading = true and then ng-disabled="isLoading". If you provide a jsfiddle\plnkr I will modify it

Comment: @OrGuz Yep,It works.Can you put your suggestion as an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set ng-disabled to true while loading, once loading is completed change it to false.

I added a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b9b5dzct/) doing so, instead of real loading I used a timeout of 5 seconds for fake loading.

This is the logic that will solve your issue.

HTML:

```
<div class="well" ng-controller="MyController">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="isLoading" 
     ng-click="myClick()">BUTTON</button> 
</div>
```

Controller:

```
function MyController($scope,$timeout) {


    $scope.myClick = function() {
        $scope.isLoading = true;

        /// Faking Loading logic
        $timeout(function(){
            $scope.isLoading = false},5000)
    };


}
```